# HOW GET FRIENDS ID IN GROUP

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-group

I use this code for get my friends where i'm a member of.but not work...!

`select uid2 from friend where uid1 IN (SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = '111111111')`

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work?

Comment: i try with facebook tools explorer.this the code error :"error": {
    "message": "Can't lookup all friends of 100004015920032 due to user's privacy settings.",
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException",
    "code": 604

Comment: I guess user 100004015920032's privacy settings don't let you look up their friends list, then?

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
select uid,gid  from group_member where gid in (select gid from group_member where uid=me()) order by gid
```

It get all the user id and group id from the group where group id is in a group in where you are member.

BUt I suggest you to split it in 2 query: get the ids of the group where you are in and then get, for each group, the ids of the members

```
select gid from group_member where uid=me()
```

and then loop through the results

select uid  from group_member where gid ={group_id}

for the users data:

Pay attention: more the query is complicated, more will be the time needed

```
select name from user where uid in(select uid  from group_member where gid in (select gid from group_member where uid=me()))
```

so i suggest, for each group:

select name from user where uid in(select uid from group_member  where gid ={group_id})

[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) is the user table reference so you can add the fields needed in addition to 'name'

Comment: its work fine.but,how i get firends data in spesific group where i member in the group .

Comment: @RatnaWulan let me know if you need something other or my answer is satisfying please